# How does a manual workflow differ from an automated Github workflow?

Tags: node.js, npm, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am attempting to reproduce as an automated github workfow the steps which allow me to manually publish a package from my local console through an opportune **.npmrc** file.

If do manually type (from the root folder of my Node.js project):

```
echo "@myorganization:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com" > .npmrc
echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:username=myname" >> .npmrc
echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=xyz" >> .npmrc
npm publish
```

I succed in publishing my package.

However, if I write in the **.yml** file:

```
on:
    release:
        types: [created]
  
jobs:     
   
    build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v3
            - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
              with:
                node-version: 18
            - run: npm ci
            - run: npm test

    publish-gpr: 
        needs: build
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        permissions: 
            packages: write
            contents: read
        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v3
            - uses: actions/setup-node@v3 
              with:
                node-version: 16
                registry-url: https://npm.pkg.github.com/              
            - name: npm publish
              env:
                NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.MY_TOKEN}
              run: |
                echo "myorganization:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com" > .npmrc
                echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:username=myname" >> .npmrc
                echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${NODE_AUTH_TOKEN:?}" >> .npmrc
                npm publish
```

I get the error:

```
...
npm notice Publishing to https://npm.pkg.github.com
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized - PUT https://npm.pkg.github.com/@myorganization%2fmyrepository - unauthenticated: User cannot be authenticated with the token provided.
...
```

so that, I suppose, the problem comes from the conversion of the environmental variable **NODE_AUTH_TOKEN** to the explicit **xyz** secret value. However, I have not been able to solve such a problem. Can you undestand what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause looks to me that the newly introduced parameter `NODE_AUTH_TOKEN` is missing in the environment.

This is noticed only later, when `npm publish` is invoked and errors.

Some hints and example:

When you convert into a workflow, start porting your command sequence into a single `run:` as it belongs together.

Also always put the `env:` before the `run:` so that the environment is visible upfront (and you spot missing parameters more easily).

Finally, error on required parameters if they are empty (`${NODE_AUTH_TOKEN:?}`), so it is as early as possible to produce the error and it is easy to localize.

```yaml
        - name: npm publish
          env:
            NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.MY_TOKEN}}    
          run: |
            echo "@myorganization:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com" >> .npmrc
            echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:username=myname" >> .npmrc
            echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${NODE_AUTH_TOKEN:?}" >> .npmrc
            npm publish
```

To make it even more failsafe, you could change the first write to .npmrc create that file by using `>` instead of `>>` which is appending. In case the file would exist (unclean build), you would not run into such a problem late. But strictly speaking this is not necessary.

Comment: thank you @hakre for your hints but after having reorganized my .yml file as shown (see my edited post) I still get the same `unauthorized` error

Comment: @user15883430: If you still get the 401 Unauthorized, then the secret appears wrong to me. Do you have a way to verify it? the `${NODE_AUTH_TOKEN:?}` will only error if unset or empty. So if it contains a wrong value, it can't catch that (however when porting to a workflow, one common mistake is to not have it set therefore I recommend this check). But **more importantly:** `env:` + `run:` need to be in the same list/array entry (`-`). You now moved it into the `- uses:` entry, `- run:` is still on its own. Take attention to the detail where `-` (hyphen-minus) are placed.

Comment: thank you @hakre I have just realized that I was already `logged in` to the registry  through the simple  `npm login` command by inserting username and token when I called the `npm publish` so that, I suppose, the `.npmrc` file was not relevant at all for the manual publication. My question is, therefore, completely misleading. I apologize for this. As soon as you confirm me to have read this comment, I will delete this post and reformulate another question, because I am still unable to make my `.yml` file work. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @user15883430: When you delete the question, this answer willl also be gone. If I may suggest you create a new question but leave this one open as it already helped you to clarify the situation. The leave a comment here under the answer with a link to the new question. When the new question is solved, you can decide whether you want to upvote/downvote and/or accept is as an answer. (I do not think the answer is particularly wrong for the question even if the question itself might have been "misleading" as you coin it.) -- in context of `npm` you may consider scripts to align local/remote build

Comment: Ok @hakre I have just opened a new question at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76562148/how-does-the-interactive-npm-login-command-differ-from-the-non-interactive-login).